# How can I recreate this synth sound?

Tags: synthesizer, replication

I'd like to recreate or at least find out if there is already a patch on some synth that sounds like this,does someone have any songs that sound similar to this?

I love this kind of sound,and I'd be grateful if someone could point me out In right direction of finding more about it sounds to me like some Italo Disco.

Answer (score 1):

Those are Italo Disco sounds alright, you can find several sounds similar to those on the Korg Legacy Collection if you are using plugins, it has an emulation of the Polysix which you can use for the pads, and it has one called Wavestation which is like a vector synthetizer which you can use for the leads, you'll just have to explore between presets and preferably learn to do a little bit of patching so you can shape the sound as you please.

This are some old songs which I find to have similar sounds, only they're better shaped and produced 
Clio - Faces:

Ivan - Fotonovela:

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a classic sound that come with the DX7, a synth used massively in the 80s pop production. Bascially its an FM-Synthesizer. So i would go for a plugin with FM Synthesis. 
There is a cool free plugin called Dexed which is aiming to replicate the sound of a DX7 maybe give it try and see if you can find something similar in the presets:
https://asb2m10.github.io/dexed/